# GDB shorten function signatures when using layout spilt?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I am using `layout split` within GDB to preview the source code above the assembly code. However, in the bottom panel (the assembly viewer) each instruction address is prefixed with the corresponding C++ function/method signature. The problem is some of my functions have 8/9 arguments and this is causing the signature to be huge, requiring me to open GDB across two monitors, just to see the assembly instructions.

Are there any GDB options to shorten the signature/replace it with something shorter?

`gdb --version` returns `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-100.el7_4.1`